scapy not working "ImportError" and "AttributeError"
PIP package scapy-python3 used to provide scapy3k, which was a fork from scapy implementing python3 compatibility since 2016. This package was included in some of the Linux distros under name of python3-scapy. Starting from scapy version 2.4 (released in March, 2018) mainstream scapy supports python3. To reduce any confusion scapy3k was renamed to kamene.
You should use either pip package kamene for scapy3k (see http://github.com/phaethon/kamene for differences in use) or mainstream scapy (pip package scapy, http://github.com/secdev/scapy).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Udit\Desktop\keylogger\spy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import sniff
  File "C:\Users\Udit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception:
        PIP package scapy-python3 used to provide scapy3k, which was a fork from scapy implementing python3 compatibility since 2016. This package was included in some of the Linux distros under name of python3-scapy. Starting from scapy version 2.4 (released in March, 2018) mainstream scapy supports python3. To reduce any confusion scapy3k was renamed to kamene.
You should use either pip package kamene for scapy3k (see http://github.com/phaethon/kamene for differences in use) or mainstream scapy (pip package scapy, http://github.com/secdev/scapy).
......................................................................................................

This is what I get every time I execute in vs output when I tried
import scapy.all as scapy 

request = scapy.ARP() 
print(request.summary())

I got "who has 0.0.0.0 says 0.0.0.0"
I am totally new to scapy help me out
I want the package to work like "from scapy import sniff, ARP, send" like those modules are not helping0.
Btw, I'm using py -v 3.11 and scapy -v 2.5 all up to date till this post.

This is an installation problem. How did you install scapy?

Actually installed it multiple times tried: pip install scapy, pip3 install scapy, pip3 install scapy-python3 and after sometime tried pip show scapy didnt locate and again tried it with pip install scapy and it worked one time as I mentioned in question idk what to do
